# How to avoid calling setTimeout in Apache ECharts SSR

Tags: settimeout, server-side-rendering, echarts

I was trying to use echarts SSR solution, but in our project the setTimeout function is forbidden to use in server side. And I did not need the animationin fact. The demo code belows:

```
function renderChart() {
    const chart = init(null, null, {
        renderer: 'svg', // 必须使用 SVG 模式
        ssr: true, // 开启 SSR
        width: 400, // 需要指明高和宽
        height: 300,
    });
    chart.setOption({
        // animation: false,
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
       },
       yAxis: {
           type: 'value'
       },
       series: [
          {
            data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
            type: 'line'
         }
     ]
    });
    return chart.renderToSVGString();
}
```

And then I found that echarts uses the zrender to paint,here is the source code in zrender:

```
import env from '../core/env.js';
var requestAnimationFrame;
requestAnimationFrame = (env.hasGlobalWindow
    && ((window.requestAnimationFrame && window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window))
        || (window.msRequestAnimationFrame && window.msRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window))
        || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame)) || function (func) {
    return setTimeout(func, 16);
};
export default requestAnimationFrame;
```

so you can see, in server side(or in nodejs),it will run setTimeout anyway in server.So is there any solution that can avoid to run the setTimeout?

I tried to set the option { animation: false }, but it did not work.